# sql query with apostrophe not saving

Tags: mysql, sql

$invoice = "L'avoutre, mais tu l'as l'astraunote va"à^ùé$sw";

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers ( invoice ) VALUES ('".$invoice."');";
```

> $query not working due to apostrophes, how do I save this?

Comment: user a parameterized query.

Comment: You can break the quotes [check](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e003c60a3ca01b2d3fd69580f43c3e41) , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @ErgestBasha I think you mean "escape the quotes". But using a prepared statement with parameters is much safer.

Comment: @Barmar , correct

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
$invoice = addslashes("L'avoutre, mais tu l'as l'astraunote va\"à^ùé\$sw");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (invoice) VALUES (?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $invoice); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Yes, I have do that but it doesn't work. 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (invoice) VALUES (?)");


 $stmt->bind_param("sss", $invoice);
 
 
 $stmt->execute();
 
 
 $stmt->close();

Comment: Edited above, change $stmt->bind_param("sss", $invoice);  to $stmt->bind_param("s", $invoice); with a single "s" since its only 1 parameter you are binding.

Comment: Yes I know, I do that but it doesn't work idk why

Comment: can you enable error reporting and share details? ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Or full example with errors: <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","db");
// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
exit();
} else {
    echo "Connected!";
}
$invoice = addslashes("L'avoutre, mais tu l'as l'astraunote va\"à^ùé\$sw");
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (invoice) VALUES (?)"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $invoice); 
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $stmt->close();
?>

Comment: You don't need to use `addslashes()` if you use query parameters. If you use both, you will get literal backslashes in the data you save to the database.